# Is 0 and 1 invertible in modulo p?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

Is 0 and 1 invertible in modulo p?

I think 0 never is while 1 always is?

E.g. 1 in modulo 13 is invertible to 13 and since 1*1=1 modulo 13.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  You are correct

Comment: $1\times 1 = 1$ so .... yes.   $0\times 1 = 0 \not \equiv 1\pmod p$ so ...no.

Answer (score 2):

For $a$ to be invertable then $ax \equiv 1 \pmod p$ must have a solution.  That's the definition.

So $1$ is invertible if and only if $1\cdot x \equiv 1 \pmod p$ has a solution. And as $1\cdot x=x$ then $1$ is invertible if and only if $x \equiv 1 \pmod p$ has a solution.  Does it?

ANd $0$ is invertible if and only if $0\cdot x \equiv  1 \pmod p$ has a solution. And as $0\cdot x = 0$ then $0$ is invertible if an only if $0 \equiv 1 \pmod p$ has a solution.  Does it?

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Math Stack Exchange

$0$ doesn't have an inverse. If it had, then, for some $k$, $0=0\cdot k\equiv 1\pmod{p}$, contradiction.

$1$ does have an inverse, which is $1$ himself.

From now on, show your attempts and knowledge when you post a question. Do not expect people to just do work for you.  I gave you an upvote for encouragement.

Comment: Or is it "which is $1$ herself"?

Comment: Might be. In my natal lnaguage all numbers are masculines and that's how we talk. So that was my pure instinct right there. Sorry.